# TimescaleDB - export all data and import into different DB instance

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, timescaledb, pg-restore

I have multiple TimescaleDB instances of the same DB running and need to collect all data from each of those and append/insert it into a single TimescaleDB. The goal is to have a single DB with all data from all instances.

I tried using pg_dump to export data from a particular DB instance for this as follows:

```
docker exec timescaledb pg_dump --data-only -Fc -U collector energy > backup.sql
```

Then tried to import that backup file into the final DB using pg_restore:

```
docker exec -i timescaledb pg_restore --data-only -Fc -U central_admin --dbname energy < backup.sql
```

But the restore generates loads of errors and googling didn't help so far:

```
pg_restore: while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: from TOC entry 5085; 0 17593 TABLE DATA hypertable collector
pg_restore: error: COPY failed for table "hypertable": ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "hypertable_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY hypertable, line 1
pg_restore: from TOC entry 5092; 0 17675 TABLE DATA chunk collector
pg_restore: error: COPY failed for table "chunk": ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "chunk_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY chunk, line 1
pg_restore: from TOC entry 5088; 0 17642 TABLE DATA dimension collector
pg_restore: error: COPY failed for table "dimension": ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dimension_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY dimension, line 1
pg_restore: from TOC entry 5090; 0 17660 TABLE DATA dimension_slice collector
pg_restore: error: COPY failed for table "dimension_slice": ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dimension_slice_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY dimension_slice, line 1
[...cut off...]
```

The destination DB is empty but the schema exists and should match the one from the source DB.

I'm using the latest Docker image *timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg14*

Comment: Do you have the same hypertable names and structure but want just the data right. It seems like you're getting some duplication based on the chunks that are subtables from the hypertables. Maybe [parallel-copy](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-parallel-copy) is a good alternative to copy the data.

Comment: Thanks @jonatasdp for that hint. This is not the ideal solution that I was hoping for but it nudged me to build two scripts that 1) dump the data each of the customer instances into a bunch of CSV files and 2) load those files into TimescaleDB. Both scripts currently use the "COPY" functionality provided by psql and work fine. I will look into parallel-copy to see how much performance boost I get. I still keep this question as "unanswered" since I was looking for a solution which automatically dumps all tables. The scripts I wrote have to be updated everytime I add/remove a table from the DB.

Comment: Makes sense @kurt! I got your point! thanks for sharing the details. I'd encourage you to bring it as an issue in the official repository, maybe more people have similar needs and the team can prioritize some fix in the regular pg_dump format.